# Salesforce HTTP Callout Headers

Tags: http, http-headers, salesforce

In Salesforce HTTP callout we use

```
HttpRequest newRequest = new HttpRequest();
```

and set the Headers like

```
newRequest.setHeader('Authorization','XXX');
newRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','XXX');
newRequest.setHeader('CustomHeader','Customparameter');
```

Apart from Authorisation and Content-Type what are the other parameters that can be set and what is their purpose. It would be great if someone can point me to a link for description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Salesforce" HttpRequest is just a System.HttpRequest according to their docs [notes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) 
so it looks like you want a [list of HttpRequest Headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

HTTP is just a protocol that (should) be pretty much standard.